# How to run undertow java app with docker

Tags: java, curl, docker, undertow

I am using undertow for my applications with docker.

I am able to do the following

1. create fat jar
2. create docker image from that
3. Run that docker image
4. Listing on 8080 and added EXPOSE 8080 in Docker file
5. curl my url from INSIDE the CONTAINER , curl localhost:8080/sample

I am facing some weird problem,

And My compose file is

```
version: '2'
services:
  login:
    image: my-image
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

with 8080 port I am not able to access the url.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY ./target/*-with-dependencies.jar /jars/service-jar.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java  -cp /jars/service-jar.jar my.Main
```

My Undertow Listener

```
Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(path)
        .build();
```

I got some link in google still not able to make it work

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2014-October/000999.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed the issue , by listening the ip to the docker containers ip address .

I changed my listener to

```
Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress())
        .setHandler(path)
        .build();
```

Now it working fine.

> "The external IP is something completely different. So in summary you
>   must set the host server for undertow as the Internal IP in the
>   Iptables created by docker"

I missed to read this line in my reference link (http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2014-October/000999.html).

My boss find out that .

Comment: Keep in mind though that you will run into issues if you use multiple docker-networks for this container. In this scenario, you should use `.addHttpListener(8080,"0.0.0.0")`, which  basically says: "listen on all ip addresses"

Comment: @ShrimpPhaser,thank you for the suggestion. this also works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your docker image?
Are you publishing port?

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 ...
```

[Related documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)